# Selenium JavascriptExecutor Calculation

Tags: javascript, selenium

I tried to do an example on JavaScriptExecutor.

Test site is: http://www.anaesthetist.com/mnm/javascript/calc.htm

Test Scenario is: 3+9=12 (Addition)

I wrote below code but it did not work. I debug the code, I saw 12 as a result on the page but at assertion point I got null value from .getText() method.

Here is my code:

```
public class CalculatorExampleTest {
static WebDriver driver;
private static String url = "http://www.anaesthetist.com/mnm/javascript/calc.htm";

//Setup Driver
@BeforeClass
public static void setupTest() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to(url);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

@Test
public void calculatorJavaScriptTest() {
    //Declare a Webdriver Wait
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    //1-) Click "9"
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='button'][onclick='AddDigit(\\'9\\')']")).click();

    //2-) Click "+"
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='button'][onclick='Operate(\\'+\\')']")).click();

    //3-) Click "3"
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='button'][onclick='AddDigit(\\'3\\')']")).click();

    //4-) Declare JavaScriptExecutor and call "Calculate()" function
    JavascriptExecutor js =(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    js.executeScript("Calculate();");

    //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='button'][onclick='Calculate()']")).click();

    //5-) Check result is 12?
    //Wrapped Anonymous Class (Synchronization)
    wait.until(textDisplayed(By.cssSelector("input[name='Display']:nth-child(1)"),"12"));

    WebElement result = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='Display']:nth-child(1)"));
    assertThat(result.getText(), is("12"));

}

//Wrapped Anonymous Class
private ExpectedCondition<Boolean> textDisplayed (final By elementFindBy, final String text){
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
            return webDriver.findElement(elementFindBy).getText().contains(text);
        }
    };
}

//Close Driver
@AfterClass
public static void quitDriver() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is the `input` element, you need to get the `value` attribute value instead of text:

```
WebElement result = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name=Display]"));
assertThat(result.getAttribute("value"), is("12"));
```

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved. I also cross checked with Selenium IDE. Its generated code is also used getAttribute instead of getText()

Comment: I did what is written in that link. Thanks @alecxe